# Show that $cd - c - d = (c - 1)(d - 1) - 1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that $cd - c - d = (c - 1)(d - 1) -1$

I mean how we convert the left-side to the right-side

I tried :
to take a common factor : $c(d - 1) - d$

but I also didn't convert it to the right-side

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Try to compute the RHS.

Comment: See Simon’s Favorite Factoring Trick. https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Simon's_Favorite_Factoring_Trick

Comment: LHS$=c(d-1)-(d-1)-1$.

Comment: @geetha290krm .... what is LHS?

Comment: LHS means left hand side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do
$$
c(d-1)-d=c(d-1)-(d-1)-1=(c-1)(d-1)-1.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @AhmadAlnajjar please click the check mark to accept the answer for all future reference. So people who come to the site first time know that this is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: done.......